# set HBase properties for Spark Job using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

During Hbase data migration I have encountered a`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: KeyValue size too large`

**In long term :**

I need to increase the properties `hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize` (from 1048576 to 10485760) in the `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml` but I can't change this file now (I need validation).

**In short term :**

I have success to import data using command :

```sh
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import \
  -Dhbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize=10485760 \
  myTable \
  myBackupFile
```

Now I need to run a Spark Job using spark-submit

What is the better way :

- Prefix the HBase properties with 'spark.' (I'm not sure it's possible and if it's works)

```sh
spark-submit \
  --conf spark.hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize=10485760
```

- Using 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions' and 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions' to explicitly transmit HBase properties

```sh
spark-submit \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dhbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize=10485760 \
  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize=10485760
```

Comment: I don't think the `spark` prefix will work, you' need to use `extraJavaOptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your code, you should be able to set these properties programmatically. I think something like this used to work for me in the past in Java:

```java
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period", SCAN_TIMEOUT); // set BEFORE you create the connection object below:
Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
```

Comment: 2 days ago I was lazy ;-) and I wanted to avoid modifying the code but it is the most effective way : Today I Made a new release with `configuration.set("hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize", HBASE_CLIENT_KEYVALUE_MAXSIZE);` Thanks