# java.net.SocketTimeoutException when scanning a HBase table with Regex filter

Tags: hbase, spark-submit

Due to the rowkey design I need perform a regex scan filter, which for my understanding scan the entire set of rowkeys of that table.

The problem I am facing is by default that limit is by default `callTimeout=60000` and I am going beyond that value.

I have been looking for solutions, but the two approaches I found so far I would like to avoid:

**Approach 1:** Modifying the hbase-client.xm file, increasing the following value:

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.client.operation.timeout</name>
    <value>1800000</value>
</property>
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to this file and anyway I can't restart the client.

**Approach 2**: Modifying the configurations of the Hbase

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;

Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

conf.set("hbase.rpc.timeout", "1800000");
conf.set("hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period", "1800000");
```

This option is better, but I will need to touch the code and a shared API, which I would prefer to avoid.

So, since I am submitting this job with spark-submit, I would like to know if it would be possible to modify this parameter in this spark submit directly, without modifying configurations files in the cluster and without modifying the code.

Related questions where I couldn't find an answer: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60053217/1773841) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30923351/1773841)